# How to display the contents of list(which contain Different controls like textbox, buttons) in table format on window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having button called Input . when I click that button the item is added into the list dynamically. for example-if we click on that button three times three items will be added to list and it  is displaying  that items(different controls like textbox,buttons etc.)

What I want = I want to display that items into the table format. when i click on the button the new item should be added to the next Row dynamically.

I have written the xaml code like this:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="PropertyPaneItems"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyPaneDataSource_P.PropertyPaneList}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</ContentControl>
```

This code is working fine but this displays Items directly i want that items into table format. in my code "PropertyPaneDataSource_P.PropertyPaneList" is my list.
I tried that by using the following code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdPanel" Background="AliceBlue">
    <DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" HeadersVisibility="Column" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="60,20" ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyPaneDataSource_P.PropertyPaneList}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
         //I Not getting What to write here to display the list                                   
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The DataTemplates for the control is like:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SimpleValueContainer}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="Value" >
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <b:ValidationBehaviour/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You should use something called `DataTemplate`. You define how you want to display certain type of data.

Comment: yes, I used the DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your list contains items of some viewmodel type and for each of those viewmodel types, you already defined an implicit `DataTemplate`, so in case of `ItemsControl`, every item is displayed correctly.

In order to display the items in a table cell, you can define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and use `ContentPresenter` to utilize your implicit `DataTemplate` definitions:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Margin="60,20"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyPaneDataSource_P.PropertyPaneList}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Items">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```